# Upload a valid APK

Tags: android, google-play

**UPDATE**
It seems that during some error happens, when release team (different team) signes the APK with the release key. We took our release generated APK and signed locally. We were able to verify the apk with *apksigner veify* command.
However, if we tried to do the same with the release key signed APK, it showed error:

> mailformed zip entry: lib/armeabi-v7a/libj2v8.so

**ORIGINAL:**

We are trying to release a new version of our application, but when we try to upload the release build Google Plays rejects with the following message: 'Upload a valid APK'. Also we can't install it on any devices.
We also have a QA artifact with different endpoints, but it works fine when you install on devices.

We successfully released the application in the last 3 years many times, never seen such an issue. Anyone ever faced this?

Summary of latest changes:

1. Integrated a vendor SDK
2. migrated to androidx
3. Minimum version if 24
4. Target and Compile SDK version is 28

Comment: How did you create the apk? Is there any differences in the creation process between release apk and QA's apk?

Comment: not really, we run the assambleQA or assambleRelease gradle command. Some update from my end: it seems there is some issue during the release key signing. I will edit the post